# On tmux 2.4 how to enter copy-mode and start a search all in one go?

Tags: tmux

I am trying to bind F1 key to:

1. Enter copy-mode
2. Start a reverse search

The only thing I found online was:

```
bind-key F1 copy-mode \; send-key ?
```

However, that doesnt seem to work on tmux 2.4.

Is there a way to have it work on all tmux versions?

Comment: how about `bind-key F1 copy-mode \; send-keys -X search-reverse`?

Comment: When clicking the F1 I see '~' on the screen and thats it

Comment: When doing `bind-key -n F1 copy-mode \; send-keys -X search-reverse` I see that tmux enters the copy-mode but doesnt start a search

Comment: If you have a previous search term, the above works on tmux 3, which is all I have access to. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked:

```
bind -n F1 copy-mode \; command-prompt -p "(search up)" "send -X search-backward \"%%%\""
bind -T copy-mode-vi F1 copy-mode \; command-prompt -p "(search up)" "send -X search-backward \"%%%\""
```