# Tmux M-f --> enter copy mode and search

Tags: linux, tmux

Can i bind M-f keys to enter in copy mode and start searching up ?

```
bind-key -n F9 copy-mode
bind-key -T copy-mode C-f command-prompt -i -I "#{pane_search_string}" -p "(search up)" "send -X search-backward-incremental \"%%%\""
```

something like this but using a single key command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On tmux 2.4 how to enter copy-mode and start a search all in one go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66430860/on-tmux-2-4-how-to-enter-copy-mode-and-start-a-search-all-in-one-go)